# Ascending order of arrays

Tags: java, arrays, integer

Ugly code I know but I need the output to display the numbers entered in ascending order. As it is written only two inputs are displayed in the output...can anyone help?

```
for(int i=1;i<=2;i++) // declares i as an integer and sets it to 1; do while i<=2, increment i
{                               
  if (numarray[i] < result0) // is numarray[1] < numarray[0]
    result0 = numarray[i];//yes sets numarray[1] = result0                     
  else 
    result1 = numarray[i]; //no sets result numarray[1] =result1

  if (numarray[i] > result1) // is numarray[2] < result1
    result2 = numarray[i]; // set numarray[2] = result1

  if(numarray[i]< result0) //if numarray[2] < result0 
    result0 = numarray[i]; //yes sets numarray[2] = result0
  else 
    result1 = numarray[i]; //no sets numarray[2] = result2                           
}
System.out.println("The numbers from smallest to largest is:" + result0 + result1 + result2);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can sort and print your array using this code:

```
Array.sort(yourArray);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(yourArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the **sort** method from the **Arrays** class in Java:

```
Arrays.sort(numarray); //Ascending 
Arrays.sort(numarray, Collections.reverseOrder()); //Descending
```